# If $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $\int_0^{\epsilon} f(x)g(x) dx >0$ for any small $\epsilon>0$, do $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have same sign near $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, inequality, monotone-functions

Let $f,g : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions such that

1. $f(0)=g(0)=0$
2. $\int_0^{\epsilon} f(x)g(x)dx >0$ for any small $\epsilon>0$.

Then, I would like to investigate about the sign of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ near $x=0$. Is it possible to conclude that there exists some $\epsilon'>0$ such that $f(x)g(x) \geq 0$ for $x \in [0,\epsilon']$ ?

Comment: hmm good question. Would anything be lost if you just let $h = fg$ and think only in terms of $h(x)$ ?

Comment: Oh, my next step is to think of integrating the fraction $g/f$ provided that $f(x)$ is nonzero near $x=0$. That is why I facforized into two functions.

Comment: In the tags you call the function(s) monotone. If you want $f$ and or $g$ to be monotone, please repeat it in the question's body

Comment: I didn't assume monotinicity. Who tagged it??

Comment: See my answer, if define $h(x)=\int_0^x f(t)g(t)dt$, then your OP is equivalent to ask about the monotonicity of $h'(x)$ at the neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @MathFail please edit your post to explain this, in current form it isn't clear to me

Comment: Yes, I add this @DavidRaveh

Answer (score 3):

Define: $h(x)=\int_0^x f(t)g(t)dt$, we can simplify your question as:

> Suppose $h(x)\ge0$ at the neighborhood of $0$, and $h(0)=0, h'(0)=0$, does it implies $h'(x)\ge0$ at the neighborhood of $0$?

The answer is false. Let $$\begin{align}h(x)&=\frac{x^{3/2}}2+x^2\sin\left(\frac1x\right),~~~\text{if}~~x\neq 0\\
\\
h(0)&=0\end{align}$$

Easy to verify, it satisfies all above conditions. But $h(x)$ is NOT monotonic increasing on any neighborhood of $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer is false.

We have several ways of constructing counterexamples. I post a seemingly complicated, but intuitive way of construction. The idea is to glue an alternating series of rescaled bump functions, such that the negative bumps are extremely smaller than adjacent positive bumps.

We choose $f(x)=x$. The choice of $g$ will be technical.

Let $\psi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ be a non-negative bump function supported on $[1,2]$ such that $\psi([4/3,5/3])=\{1\}$.

We choose

$$g(x)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-2^j}\psi(2^{2j}x)-\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}2^{-10^j}\psi(2^{2j+1}x).$$

You can check smoothness of $g$ by direct calculation. Naively speaking, although we are attaching shrinking copies of unit bump function $\psi$, the size shrinks extremely faster than the shrinking support, so we have that.

You can also check that $g$ is negative on intervals $[\frac{4}{3}2^{-2j-1},\frac{5}{3}2^{-2j-1}]$, in particular $g$ is not non-negative on any interval of the form $[0,\epsilon]$.

Since $g$ is negative on the intervals $[\frac{4}{3}\cdot2^{-2j-1},\frac{5}{3}2^{-2j-1}]$, so we have $\int_0^t f(x)g(x)dx>0$ for every $t>0$ once we showed for $j\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$\int_{\frac{4}{3}2^{-2j}}^{\frac{5}{3}2^{-2j}}x2^{-2^j}\psi(2^{2j}x)dx>\int_{\frac{4}{3}2^{-2j-1}}^{\frac{5}{3}2^{-2j-1}}x2^{-10^j}\psi(2^{2j+1}x)dx,$$and this is just change of variable ($d(2x)$).